# Image cover full screen leaves white space at bottom

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want my image to cover the background completely. Further, I don't want scroll bars if there is no content in either direction besides the background.

The following is the best I can get except I get about 1 inch white space on bottom and horizontal scroll to about 95%.

#### The SCSS

```
body, html {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.workspace {
  background: url("../../../assets/Images/WhatIsHunter.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: is it the same if you use "100vh" instead of "100%"  ?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, percentage units of `height` property are relative to parent's height. So `100%` can mean different things based on where `.workspace` resides in the DOM.

To cover the whole viewport, use `vh` units.

```
.workspace {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

From [MDN article on units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) (emphasis mine):

> `vw`, `vh`: Respectively these are 1/100th of the width of the viewport, and **1/100th of the height of the viewport**.

So one hundred of those would make the whole height of the viewport, which is what you need.

Comment: Thanks... I do typically use vw and vh.  The .workspace is at the very top of the router-outlet.
I changed height and added width:
.workspace {
  background: url("../../../assets/Images/Features2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;;
  background-position: 0px 60px;
  background-size: cover;

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

Some views seem okay though I get a scroll bar thats about 95% for both width and height yet the image does cover the screen. 
BUT I have one view that is leaving white space.  It makes me wonder if I shouldn't just resize the image to make it taller ???

Comment: Use `100%` for width and `100vh` for height to avoid issues with the scrollbar on platforms where it takes up space.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the fact that body need not necessarily cover the whole of the webpage hence try the following code:

```
  body{
       height:100%;
       background-size:cover;
      }
   html{
       height:100%;
       }
```